# Only one module implements hook_tokens()?

Tags: hooks, tokens

I've declared a `[module-name]_tokens()` hook but when I output the contents of `module_implements('tokens')`, only my module appears in the list.
I know that there are many more modules that implement `hook_menu()`; why do I get only my module listed? Where shall I look for possible errors?

Comment: There are 8 modules that implement it http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/implementations/hook_tokens/7

Comment: I know, but why do I get only my module listed?

Comment: It returns perfectly for me, try clearing your cache

Comment: Tried that. Only if I call `module_implements($hook, $sort = FALSE, $reset = FALSE)` with the last parameter set to false and immediately call `module_implements('tokens')`, then the list is complete. Otherwise, it lists just my module. I cannot explain why.

Answer (score 0):

```
$hooks = module_implements('tokens');
print_r($hooks);
```

It returns the follwoing

> Array
>       (
>        [0] => token
>        [1] => date
>       [2] => domain
>       [3] => entity_token
>       [4] => facetapi
>       [5] => logintoboggan
>       [6] => name
>       [7] => node
>       [8] => scheduler
>       [9] => system
>       [10] => taxonomy
>       [11] => token_custom
>       [12] => user
>       [13] => views
>       [14] => field
>       [15] => menu )

The only place which i see is it is cached, try clearing the cache or try the following

```
 module_implements('tokens', FALSE, TRUE)
```

The third params is reset to reset the cache.

Comment: Tried that. Only if I call `module_implements($hook, $sort = FALSE, $reset = FALSE)` with the last parameter set to false and immediately call `module_implements('tokens')`, then the list is complete. Otherwise, it lists just my module. I cannot explain why.

Comment: If you have tried the same in a separate file and got the same result, Then i am sorry i do not have much idea in it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work :(